# JSON Deserialization of list of objects

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am trying to serialize and deserialize objects sent between a client and a server as JSON. I wrap all messages from the client in a simple Request-object that looks like this:

```
class Request
{
    public string Command { get; set; }
    public object[] Arguments { get; set; }
}
```

The array of Arguments can be any type of object that is needed for the selected command. On the server I then deserialize and want the Request to look exactly the same with the same type of objects in the Arguments array.

I have tried the JavascriptSerialization included with .Net and Json.Net, but both have troubles with some object types in the arguments list.
Strings, ints and other basic stuff works nicely, but a for example a Guid always pops out as a string after deserialization.

<del>Other complex objects becomes "JObject" when using Json.Net.</del> (I got help from @jlvaquero to come around this.)

Does anyone have suggestions of how to make the deserialization as correct as possible?

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/V3HKol

Comment: Try this https://dotnetfiddle.net/GSlwIR

Comment: @jlvaquero I have updated the dotnetfiddle so you can see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [TypeNameHandling](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializetypenamehandling.htm) settings.

If the JSON string include the runtime type in each Serialized Object then JSon.Net deserialize it matching the runtime Type.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Request r = new Request();
        r.Arguments[0] = new TestObject("111111");
        r.Arguments[1] = new TestObject("222222");

        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
});
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Request deserializedr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(output, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
});

        Console.WriteLine(deserializedr.Command);
        Console.WriteLine(((TestObject)(deserializedr.Arguments[0])).Name );
        Console.WriteLine(((TestObject)(deserializedr.Arguments[0])).ID);
        Console.WriteLine(((TestObject)(deserializedr.Arguments[1])).Name );
        Console.WriteLine(((TestObject)(deserializedr.Arguments[1])).ID);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
    public class Request
{
        public Request(){
            Command = "boquepasa";
            Arguments = new Object[2];
        }
    public string Command { get; set; }
    public object[] Arguments { get; set; }
}

public class TestObject
{
    public TestObject(string name)
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "$type": "Request, ConsoleApplication1",
  "Command": "boquepasa",
  "Arguments": {
    "$type": "System.Object[], mscorlib",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$type": "TestObject, ConsoleApplication1",
        "Name": "111111",
        "ID": "739479b5-9034-451f-9b58-abcf4c7671f1"
      },
      {
        "$type": "TestObject, ConsoleApplication1",
        "Name": "222222",
        "ID": "f6ea82d5-fa3d-481d-812e-baf9fab49a86"
      }
    ]
  }
}
boquepasa
111111
739479b5-9034-451f-9b58-abcf4c7671f1
222222
f6ea82d5-fa3d-481d-812e-baf9fab49a86
```

If you do `r.Arguments[2] = Guid.NewGuid()` JSON.Net deserialize it as a `String`. I have opened a issue into [Newtonsoft.Json repoisotry](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json) and while we wait for a response I had forked original github repository to add `Guid` in `Object Array` support. My repo is [here](https://github.com/jlvaquero/Newtonsoft.Json) and works well with this specific issue but it is not tested beyond this example so use it at your own risk.

Comment: Still, if any of the arguments in the Request is a Guid, it will deserialize to a string so this will not work.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand you. When you do  r.Arguments[2] = Guid.NewGuid(); Json.Net doesn't include runtime type and then fails in deserialization.

Comment: @einord. I have update the answer. JSON.Net doesn't support what you need right now.

Comment: Thanks @jlvaquero! Hopefully the repo will be included and fix this issue :) I believe that if json.net included the $type data even for basic data types if specified with the TypeNameHandling property this would solve the problem. I guess there might be similar problems with 32-bit and 64-bit integers, double vs decimal and float etc.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to include the type information by setting the `JsonSerializerSettings` in Json.Net to

```
new JsonSerializerSettings
{
     TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
}
```

This will include a new property on the json string called `$type` that gives Json.Net a hint when deserializing the object.

You would need this `JsonSerializerSettings` on both sides of the serialization for this to work properly.

More information here: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializetypenamehandling.htm

**Example**

```
    class ExampleClass
    {
        public string StringProperty { get; set; }
        public int IntProperty { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var objects = new object[]
            {
                new ExampleClass(),
                new StringBuilder()
            };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objects, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
            });

            Console.WriteLine(json);

            var deserializedObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
            });

            foreach (var type in (object[])deserializedObjects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(type.GetType());
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Outputs

```
{
    "$type": "System.Object[], mscorlib",
    "$values": [{
        "$type": "ConsoleApplication8.ExampleClass, ConsoleApplication8",
        "StringProperty": null,
        "IntProperty": 0
    },
    {
        "$type": "System.Text.StringBuilder, mscorlib",
        "m_MaxCapacity": 2147483647,
        "Capacity": 16,
        "m_StringValue": "",
        "m_currentThread": 0
    }]
}

ConsoleApplication8.ExampleClass
System.Text.StringBuilder
```

Comment: This will not work with the array of Objects. Json.Net will add $type property at the level of Arguments  array and not for each element of this array.

Comment: The link provided in the answer shows that it will, in fact, include type information for all elements of the array. Json.Net does not require type information for primitives so it will not include it, but for complex types, the type property will be included.

Comment: Just added an example as an illustration

Comment: @MichałKomorowski is right as it does not properly work with all types. Json.Net does it properly on complex types, but as in my case I use a lot of Guid properties and they are not typed and as I said in the description they deserialize as strings. This can make the entire object return as JObject instead.